# Server side filtering of Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase db structure as follows:

```
{
  "listings" : {
    "-KOt8OUGkUphoMyqEXJ2" : {
      "created" : 1470911323208,
      "ends" : 1470911323209,
      "make" : "LONDON TAXIS INT",
      "model" : "TX4 BRONZE",
      "status" : "For Sale",
    },
    "-KOt97_P8sJW7woED4aH" : {
      "created" : 1470911515115,
      "ends" : 1471775515000,
      "make" : "NISSAN",
      "model" : "QASHQAI N-TEC",
      "status" : "For Sale",
    },
    "-KOt_BYYUEaXu_LNvnUv" : {
      "created" : 1470918609414,
      "ends" : 1471782609000,
      "make" : "MAZDA",
      "model" : "3 TS",
      "status" : "For Sale",
    }
  }
}
```

I use GeoFire to get keys for listings in a given radius. I then use observeSingleEventOfType to return the listing for the key. This all works fine.

However, I would like to only return a listing if the "ends" timestamp > current time. I have tried the following approach:

```
geoQueryHandle = geoQuery.observeEventType(.KeyEntered, withBlock: {(key, location) in

        let listingRef = self.ref.child("listings").child(key)
        let now = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        let query = listingRef.queryStartingAtValue(now, childKey: "ends")

        query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in

            if let listing = Listing(snapshot: snapshot, location: location) {
                //...populate my tableview
            }
        }
})
```

Can anyone advise me on why my query isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on "isn't working"? Does the withBlock not execute, or you don't get the snapshot you expect, or something else?

Comment: Hi Travis, sorry for the "isn't working"...to clarify, the withBlock doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries apply ordering/filtering to the properties of the child nodes of the location where you execute them.

```
queryLocation
  child1
    filterProperty: filterValue
  child2
    filterProperty: filterValue
```

Since your `listingRef` already points to a specific listing, the order/filter you add will apply to child nodes one level deeper.

The simplest way to get your use-case working seems to simply filter the node client-side:

```
let listingRef = self.ref.child("listings").child(key)

query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
    if let listing = Listing(snapshot: snapshot, location: location) {
        let now = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        // TODO: exit if snapshot.child("ends").getValue() < now
        //...populate my tableview
    }
}
```

A more complex, but more efficient, way to accomplish this would be to remove the expired events from the Geofire location.

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank. My current solution uses filtering on the client side exactly as you describe. I have also looked into removing the expired events from the GeoFire location, however, it's how to trigger the removal when the 'end' timestamp has passed. I assume (without some human intervention in the app), this would need to be done by a server side process that runs through all listings looking for expired records and deletes the Geofire location?

Comment: It could easily be done client-side, simply have the client remove the key when it encounters an event that has expired. If would fit right into the method you have already. Since it's a remove operation, multiple clients doing the same operation won't make a difference.

Comment: I was a bit concerned about any potential impact on security of the data...however, having thought it through, I don't think it matters. Thanks for the suggestion, will give it a shot.

Comment: For security you could only allow data to be deleted when its older than now. Something with `newData.exists() || data.child('ends').val() < now` should do the trick there.

Comment: I only want to remove the GeoFire location though, not the listing. The 'ends' value isn't on the GeoFire location to be able to apply that rule....or, am I still out of my Firebase depth? ;-)